# Split a List into a List of Lists, splitting on an element

Tags: c#, linq, aggregate

Can the following be rewritten so that is uses LINQ, (rather an these old-fashioned `foreach` loops)

```
IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> SplitIntoSections<T>(IEnumerable<T> content, 
    Func<T, bool> isSectionDivider)
{
    var sections = new List<List<T>>();
    sections.Add(new List<T>());
    foreach (var element in content)
    {
        if (isSectionDivider(element))
        {
            sections.Add(new List<T>());
        }
        else
        {
            sections.Last().Add(element);
        }
    }

    return sections;
}
```

I thought I almost had an way of doing this, (it involved FSharp colections) when i realised that it could be done with a `foreach` loop.

Comment: I reckon it'll involve the `group x by` syntax but I'm not good enough at LINQ to post a proper answer. :(

Comment: I cna evision 2 solutions, one does use group by. (and is >O(n) (though might only be O(2n)),
The other uses Aggregate, and since Aggregate is Linq for F# Fold, it must be able to express every operation you can do to a list

Comment: Correct me if true, are the dividers added to groups? from what I see, the dividers are left out.

Comment: Indeed, they should be left out. Kind of Like in String.Split

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want to use LINQ here.  You aren't going to be able to order and group the proper way without doing something gnarly.

The easy thing to do is to take your code and make it defer execution using the [`yield` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9k7k7cf0.aspx).  An easy way to do this is as follows:

```
IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> SplitIntoSections<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, 
    Func<T, bool> sectionDivider)
{
    // The items in the current group.
    IList<T> currentGroup = new List<T>();

    // Cycle through the items.
    foreach (T item in source)
    {
        // Check to see if it is a section divider, if
        // it is, then return the previous section.
        // Also, only return if there are items.
        if (sectionDivider(item) && currentGroup.Count > 0)
        {
            // Return the list.
            yield return currentGroup;

            // Reset the list.
            currentGroup = new List<T>();
        }

        // Add the item to the list.
        currentGroup.Add(item);
    }

    // If there are items in the list, yield it.
    if (currentGroup.Count > 0) yield return currentGroup;
}
```

There's a problem here; for very large groups, it's inefficient to store the sub-groups in a list, they should be streamed out as well.  The problem with your approach is that you have a function that is required to be called on each item; it interferes with the stream operation since one can't reset the stream backwards once the grouping is found (as you effectively need *two* methods that yield results).

Comment: I was starting to play with this one when you posted your answer. Agree wholeheartedly. Would not be as much against LINQ if the assignment in the if statement branches were equivalent. +1

Answer (score 0):

You could use a side-effect which is only used within a well-defined area... it's pretty smelly, but:

```
int id = 0;
return content.Select(x => new { Id = isSectionDivider(x) ? id : ++id,
                                 Value = x })
              .GroupBy(pair => pair.Id, pair.Value)
              .ToList();
```

There must be a better alternative though... `Aggregate` will get you there if necessary...

```
return content.Aggregate(new List<List<T>>(), (lists, value) => {
                             if (lists.Count == 0 || isSectionDivider(value)) {
                                 lists.Add(new List<T>());
                             };
                             lists[lists.Count - 1].Add(value);
                             return lists;
                         });
```

... but overall I agree with [casperOne](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7636346/split-a-list-into-a-list-of-lists-splitting-on-an-element/7636521#7636521), this is a situation best handled outside LINQ.

Comment: Lol. As I look at this answer, it says "edited 22 hours ago" by "casperOne" and the last sentence in the answer is "...but overall I agree with casperOne"...

Answer (score 0):

Here's an inefficient but pure LINQ solution:

```
var dividerIndices = content.Select((item, index) => new { Item = item, Index = index })
                            .Where(tuple => isSectionDivider(tuple.Item))
                            .Select(tuple => tuple.Index);


return new[] { -1 }
        .Concat(dividerIndices)
        .Zip(dividerIndices.Concat(new[] { content.Count() }),
            (start, end) => content.Skip(start + 1).Take(end - start - 1));
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I use one LINQ method here, though it's not particularly in the spirit of your question, I think:

```
static class Utility
{
    // Helper method since Add is void
    static List<T> Plus<T>(this List<T> list, T newElement)
    {
        list.Add(newElement);
        return list;
    }

    // Helper method since Add is void
    static List<List<T>> PlusToLast<T>(this List<List<T>> lists, T newElement)
    {
        lists.Last().Add(newElement);
        return lists;
    }

    static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> SplitIntoSections<T>
         (IEnumerable<T> content, 
          Func<T, bool> isSectionDivider)
    {
        return content.Aggregate(                      // a LINQ method!
            new List<List<T>>(),                       // start with empty sections
            (sectionsSoFar, element) =>
            isSectionDivider(element)
                ? sectionsSoFar.Plus(new List<T>())
                  // create new section when divider encountered

                : sectionsSoFar.PlusToLast(element)
                  // add normal element to current section
            );
    }
}
```

I trust you will note the complete lack of error checking, should you decide to use this code...